# R_Extracting data for a particular date form a zoo object

Tags: r, extract

Hi I have a zoo time series (interval-1 min) contains rainfall data from multiple rain gauges for a month which looks like

```
head(precApr)
                    RG.1 RG.2 RG..4 RG.5 RG.6 RG.7 RG.8 RG.9 RG.10 RG.12 RG.13
2008-04-06 00:00:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:01:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:02:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:03:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:04:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:05:00    0    0     0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
                    RG.14 RG.15 RG.16 RG.17 RG.18
2008-04-06 00:00:00     0     0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:01:00     0     0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:02:00     0     0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:03:00     0     0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:04:00     0     0     0     0     0
2008-04-06 00:05:00     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now I want to extract the data for a particular date, say 25. I used the following code using `xts::.indexDate`

```
precAprxts=as.xts(precApr)
precApr25=precAprxts[.indexDate(25)]
```

But this just gives the following answer whereas I would expect a time series of that day

```
  precApr25
  ## RG.1 RG.2 RG..4 RG.5 RG.6 RG.7 RG.8 RG.9 RG.10 RG.12 RG.13 RG.14 RG.15
  ## RG.16 RG.17 RG.18
```

Does anybody know what's the problem with my code or Is there are any other method to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `z` is a zoo series (as stated in the question) then subscripting and `window` should both work.  In the second and third examples we have assumed that the index is of `POSIXct` class:

```
 z[4, ] # fourth row

 window(z, as.POSIXct("2008-04-06 00:03:00"))

 window(z, as.POSIXct("2008-04-06")) # assumes time is 00:00:00
```

**Added** One can also subscript with a time:

```
 z[as.POSIXct("2008-04-06 00:00:00"), ]

 z[as.POSIXct("2008-04-06 00:00:00")] # same
```

See `?window.zoo` for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Haven't used `window` before and I think it's more straight forward than what I was trying to do.